# Symbol lookup error when using -Wl,--defsym GCC option

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, g++

I've got a question regarding using one of the GCC linker options: -Wl,--defsym.

Some time ago I decided to rewrite one of my projects in C++ but without using its standard library and without even linking to it (I compile .cpp source files to object files using C++ compiler but I link them using C compiler).

For that I used following compiler flags:

```
-fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs
```

And following linker options:

```
-Wl,--defsym -Wl,__cxa_pure_virtual=0
```

Using those flags I got my shared library compiling and linking fine.
But after I try to use my shared library in some simple program (also compiled and linked using above flags) I get following error while running it:

```
examples/bin/blink: symbol lookup error: examples/bin/libblink.so: undefined symbol: __cxa_pure_virtual
```

where blink is the name of the executable and libblink.so is the name of my shared library.

I tried to fix it and it looks like replacing --Wl,--defsym linker flag (for both executable and library) with this function:

```
extern "C" void __cxa_pure_virtual
{
    while (true);
}
```

does the job. Why is the --Wl,--defsym not working in this case?
I'd also like to mention that I tested this under Windows and it works fine there.

Comment: *Rerite one of my projects in C++ but without using its standard library and without even linking to it* why on earth? Standard library is what gives C++ it's power!

Comment: There's plenty of reasons why one would not like his program being linked to C++ std lib. One of them would be space limit on embedded devices.

Comment: What I do not understand is: did you used virtual function calls? How should that work without having runtime support?

Comment: I did use virtual function calls and of course they will work without "runtime support". Virtual function call is just dereferencing vtable pointer so there's no need for c++ std lib to do anything. Also I changed from C to C++ just for oop (I was tired of doing oop-like code in C) and I did not want to sacrifice the binary size for that.

Comment: A compiler does not link. There is no GNU C-linker.

Comment: I've written a kernel in C++, needed to do this as well. Probably you'd want to print out a diagnostic message from `__cxa_pure_virtual` (since it'd never happen anyway ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I've found an answer to my question.

Changing the symbol address from 0 to any other value fixes my issue.
So instead of having:

```
--Wl,--defsym --Wl,__cxa_pure_virtual=0
```

I have:

```
--Wl,--defsym --Wl,__cxa_pure_virtual=1
```

This way runtime linker does not look for a symbol (which I think is the case when the address is set to 0).